# Send message to specific register user from mysql database ratchet php

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

I am trying to build messaging tools in my application i am stuck on How to send message to specific register user fetch from database i am new to websocket ratchet.

i want to build something like fiverr, upwork chat where customer can contact to sellers

here is my code

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input, button { padding: 10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="message" autocomplete="off" />
        <button onclick="transmitMessage()">Send</button>
        <script>
            // Create a new WebSocket.
            var socket  = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080?value=450');

            // Define the 
            var message = document.getElementById('message');

            function transmitMessage() {
                socket.send( message.value );
            }

            socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                document.getElementById('ids').innerHTML=  e.data;
            }
        </script>
        <div id="ids"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**socket.php**

```
namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Socket implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {

        // Store the new connection in $this->clients
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {

        foreach ( $this->clients as $client ) {

            if ( $from->resourceId == $client->resourceId ) {
                continue;
            }

            $client->send( "Client $from->resourceId said $msg" );
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You only have a message field, but you need to let the user state a recipient somehow. One way is to display the button on a user's profile, in which case you can store the currently visited page in the server's session. As in: user clicks link to profile of user #12345, 12345 is stored in session and user profile 12345 is displayed to user. User clicks button, message is sent to user #12345.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i understand but i  want to know how can i start new connection with specific userid passing from index.html to php code  / socket.php

Comment: Right, `socket.send({ message: message.value, toUser: someID });` (in case you're asking how to send a message directly from user A to user B, that's not possible; you send the message to the server, then forward it to the target user via their socket connection)

Comment: my question, how to make connection base on user id

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Is this supposed to be a live online chat? What if the target user isn't online?

Comment: just lets say, i have 10 users register in mysql database i want to send message to user which ID number in table is 5 how can i do this ?

Comment: Add a message table to your DB and insert a new row containing relevant data (sender id, recipient id, timestamp, text). *If* we're talking about an online chat where both sender and recipient are currently visiting the website, you need to associate the socket with the DB id. You can do this by keeping an array in the session and adding an object that stores the user's id and their socket.